# Referencing domain objects from external grails project - Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails applications

Tags: grails, grails-orm, integration-testing, grails-domain-class

I have two Grails Projects in Eclipse.  I am referencing one project inside the other with the Configure Build Path setup.  Running tests however throws an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.example.domain.Phone] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.`

Normally this is fixed with a @Mock (using Mockito) or mockDomain(), but I am not in a unit test so these items are not seen.

How can I test my service layer through an integration test if it cannot see my domain objects that I need to use?  These domain objects are separated because of the need to use them across multiple projects.

Answer (score 2):

If your GORM classes are not in the same package as your `Application` class then you need to add the `ComponentScan` annotation to the `Application` class to indicate where you GORM classes are. Example:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages=['foo.bar', 'my.company'])
class Application {
....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing tests do not forget:

1. Annotations in Spec. `@IntegrationTest` is important

   ```
   @ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader, classes = ConfigTest)
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   @IntegrationTest
   class PaymentServiceSpec extends Specification{
     // Tests with GORM entities
   }
   ```
2. Class where hibernate is injected

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @Import(HibernateGormAutoConfiguration)
   class CoreConfigTest {
   }
   ```
3. Because of @IntegrationTest it is necessary to have an Application class for tests

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   class TestApplication {
     static void main(String[] args) {
       run TestApplication, args
     }
   }
   ```

I am using this dependencies:

```
  runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41'

  compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.1.0.RELEASE") {
      exclude module: 'spring-boot-cli'
      exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    }

  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.2.2.RELEASE")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is GORM for Spring Boot available. Examples in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm/

If you are writing tests, you can use the [HibernateTestMixin](https://github.com/grails/grails-datastore-test-support/blob/master/src/test/groovy/grails/test/mixin/hibernate/HibernateMixinSpec.groovy) or use [HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4/src/test/groovy/grails/orm/bootstrap/HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializerSpec.groovy) to initialize GORM.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. I already configured an external application using Spring boot and GORM, using Groovy entities packaged as a Jar file. However, Spring boot also complains that the entities are being used outside of a Grails application. If I put them inside the same java package as the application, then it works. Why? :P. Thanks!